# Accordion in Asp.Net MVC using html, css and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to implement an accordion in my application. The accordion itself displays correctly but upon clicking the '+' to open up the description, this is where nothing happens. When user clicks on each '+' , the tab should open to display the corresponding description. Can anyone see whats causing it to not work? see below code.

**HTML** (Just a snippet of one of the tabs)

```html
<div class="accord-tab-box">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="accordion-box">

          <div class="accord-elem">
            <div class="accord-title">
              <h5><i class="fa fa-money fa-fw"></i>Software Development</h5>
              <a class="accord-link" href="#"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="accord-content">
              <p>IT related have a team of software developers who are skilled in Open source Java, Spring, Hibernate, Struts, GWT; DotNet framework and have written many web based systems:<br />• Requisition system<br />• Tender management system <br />•
                Invoice tracking system<br />• Our team has more than 20 years experience in Software development life cycle. Reference sites: <br />• KZN Department of Works;<br />• KZN Department Of Education;<br />• EC DEDEAT;<br /><br />• Neha Shipping;<br
                /><br />• SJS Consulting<br /> </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.container .content {}

hr,
.borderedbox {
  border-color: #D7D7D7;
}

.inspace-5 {
  padding: 5px;
}

.imgl {
  margin: 0 15px 10px 0;
  clear: left;
}

.imgr {
  margin: 0 0 10px 15px;
  clear: right;
}

.fl_left,
.imgl {
  float: left;
}

.fl_right,
.imgr {
  float: right;
}

.borderedbox {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: darkgray;
}

.accord-tab-box {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.accordion-box {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.accord-elem {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.accord-title {
  padding: 16px 14px;
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  position: relative;
}

.accord-title h5 {
  padding-right: 48px;
}

.accord-title h5 i {
  color: #007aff;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

a.accord-link {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 46px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  background: url('/Content/MyTemplate/images/add.png') center center no-repeat;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.accord-elem.active a.accord-link {
  background: url('/Content/MyTemplate/images/substract.png') center center no-repeat;
}

a.accord-link.opened {
  background: url('/Content/MyTemplate/images/substract.png') center center no-repeat;
}

.accord-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 22px;
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  border-top: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.accord-content span.image-content {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 22px;
  background: #007aff;
}

.accord-content span.logo-content {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 110px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.accord-content span.image-content i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 68px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.accord-content span.logo-content i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 68px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.accord-elem.active .accord-content {
  display: block;
}

.why-convertible-box {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.why-convertible-box h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.why-convertible-box h1 span {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.why-convertible-box h1 i {
  color: #0a9dbd;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.why-convertible-box p {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.why-convertible-box p a {
  color: #0076f9;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

**JS**

```js
 var clickElem = $('a.accord-link');

    clickElem.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this),
   parentCheck = $this.parents('.accord-elem'),
   accordItems = $('.accord-elem'),
   accordContent = $('.accord-content');

        if (!parentCheck.hasClass('active')) {

            accordContent.slideUp(400, function () {
                accordItems.removeClass('active');
            });
            parentCheck.find('.accord-content').slideDown(400, function () {
                parentCheck.addClass('active');
            });

        } else {

            accordContent.slideUp(400, function () {
                accordItems.removeClass('active');
            });

        }
    });
```

Comment: this code working fine, you may forgot to link jquery

Answer (score 2):

maybe you forgot to link jquery

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var clickElem = $('a.accord-link');

    clickElem.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this),
   parentCheck = $this.parents('.accord-elem'),
   accordItems = $('.accord-elem'),
   accordContent = $('.accord-content');

        if (!parentCheck.hasClass('active')) {

            accordContent.slideUp(400, function () {
                accordItems.removeClass('active');
            });
            parentCheck.find('.accord-content').slideDown(400, function () {
                parentCheck.addClass('active');
            });

        } else {

            accordContent.slideUp(400, function () {
                accordItems.removeClass('active');
            });

        }
    });
    });
```

```css
.container .content {}

hr,
.borderedbox {
  border-color: #D7D7D7;
}

.inspace-5 {
  padding: 5px;
}

.imgl {
  margin: 0 15px 10px 0;
  clear: left;
}

.imgr {
  margin: 0 0 10px 15px;
  clear: right;
}

.fl_left,
.imgl {
  float: left;
}

.fl_right,
.imgr {
  float: right;
}

.borderedbox {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: darkgray;
}

.accord-tab-box {
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.accordion-box {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.accord-elem {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.accord-title {
  padding: 16px 14px;
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  position: relative;
}

.accord-title h5 {
  padding-right: 48px;
}

.accord-title h5 i {
  color: #007aff;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

a.accord-link {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 46px;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  background: url('/Content/MyTemplate/images/add.png') center center no-repeat;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.accord-elem.active a.accord-link {
  background: url('/Content/MyTemplate/images/substract.png') center center no-repeat;
}

a.accord-link.opened {
  background: url('/Content/MyTemplate/images/substract.png') center center no-repeat;
}

.accord-content {
  display: none;
  padding: 22px;
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  border-top: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.accord-content span.image-content {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 22px;
  background: #007aff;
}

.accord-content span.logo-content {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 110px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.accord-content span.image-content i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 68px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.accord-content span.logo-content i {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 68px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.accord-elem.active .accord-content {
  display: block;
}

.why-convertible-box {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.why-convertible-box h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.why-convertible-box h1 span {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.why-convertible-box h1 i {
  color: #0a9dbd;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.why-convertible-box p {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.why-convertible-box p a {
  color: #0076f9;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accord-tab-box">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="accordion-box">

          <div class="accord-elem">
            <div class="accord-title">
              <h5><i class="fa fa-money fa-fw"></i>Software Development</h5>
              <a class="accord-link" href="#"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="accord-content">
              <p>IT related have a team of software developers who are skilled in Open source Java, Spring, Hibernate, Struts, GWT; DotNet framework and have written many web based systems:<br />• Requisition system<br />• Tender management system <br />•
                Invoice tracking system<br />• Our team has more than 20 years experience in Software development life cycle. Reference sites: <br />• KZN Department of Works;<br />• KZN Department Of Education;<br />• EC DEDEAT;<br /><br />• Neha Shipping;<br
                /><br />• SJS Consulting<br /> </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I did add the reference on my main layout page but for some reason it wasn't picking up. Ive now refenced it on the page the html accordion is in and it works. Thanks